# Setting DACL of registry key using SDDL

Tags: .net, windows, powershell, security, powershell-5.1

I am trying to replace a old script using [regini.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/application-management/change-registry-values-permissions) with the `Set-Acl` Powershell Cmdlet.

`regini.exe` is called on a file with the following contents:

```
\registry\machine\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\mykey [1 5]
```

This disables inheritence and gives full access to "CREATOR OWNER" and "Administrators". If I retrieve the SDDL for the Security Descriptor via `Get-Acl`, I get the following result: `O:SYG:SYD:P(A;CI;KA;;;CO)(A;CI;KA;;;BA)`

The following script is my idea for a powershell based version:

```
$keyAcl = New-Object System.Security.AccessControl.RegistrySecurity
$keyAcl.SetSecurityDescriptorSddlForm('D:P(A;CI;KA;;;CO)(A;CI;KA;;;BA)')
Set-Acl -AclObject $keyAcl -Path 'HKLM:\Software\WOW6432Node\mykey'
```

However, if I retrieve the Security Descriptor SDDL after running the script, I get a different result: `O:SYG:SYD:PAI(A;CIIO;KA;;;CO)(A;;KA;;;SY)(A;CI;KA;;;BA)`

Notice the following changes:

- `AI` was added, which forces the inheritance to the exiting keys
- The entry for "CREATOR OWNER" got a `IO` flag, which limits it to subkeys
- An entry `(A;;KA;;;SY)` was added, which gives SYSTEM full access to the key itsself

As far as I can tell this Security Descriptor should have a similar effect, since System is the owner. However, I would prefer if the new Powershell-based script did exactly the same as the old `regini`-based script.

Why does DACL created by `Set-Acl` differ from the one i specified? Is there a way to force `Set-Acl` to set the exact `DACL`?